# ASP.NET MVC: after adding this specific static content mime map not loading any other static file in localhost

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, azure-web-app-service

I've added mime map for mp4 video to play in published in app service because it was causing an error "file not found".

Then I added mime map for mp4 now video is playing, but when I run in local, then none of the static content is getting loaded.

My `web.config` changes for mp4:

```
<staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />
</staticContent>
```

When I comment this line in local, then it's working, but then I won't be able to play mp4 videos in app service publish.

Comment: Please check whether you have `app.UseStaticFiles();` in your `Program.cs` file.

Comment: It's .NET MVC we don't have `Program.cs` file.

Comment: Could you please share your code once.

Comment: Since it's MVC not Core we have only global.asax file only.

Comment: protected void Application_Start()
        {
            MvcHandler.DisableMvcResponseHeader = true;
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        }

Comment: @Red-Dot Thanks for providing your code in the comments.  Please [edit] the question so your code isn't buried in the comments. Will make it easier for people to answer your question.